# Keep console open in Sublime Text 3 even when using `find`

Tags: console, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, build

I have started using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) to run my website build process.

As part of the process is linting I need to ideally have eyes on the console log for any errors. Therefore rather than running it in `Terminal` I'd prefer to be able to run it inside Sublime Text 3.

I have already found the `gulp` package which allows quick access to my local gulp commands from within the editor. Running `gulp watch` in this will activate my watch process and warn me of any linting/compile errors. However if I use `Ctrl+F` the console disappears to open the find dialogue, and I presume this ends my watch process too.

So how can I use things like find without closing the console? Ideally I'd like the console to require explicit instruction to close, so I don't accidentally terminate my watch process and can see that it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not console but build result. You may reopen it from Tools->Build Results->Show Build Results. I admit this is confusing.

Comment: Will using that option keep it open if I use the Find dialogue or press Esc?

Comment: That option will reopen the "console"(which is called Build Result in Sublime Text) but it will not keep the console open when you try to find.